# grunt-ts watch not working when file changed

Tags: typescript, grunt-ts

I am using grunt:

```
  "dev-build": {
                src: ["src/**/*.ts", "typings/vendors.d.ts","typings/tsd.d.ts", "!libs/**/*.ts"],
                    outDir: "artifacts/dev",
                    watch: "src/**/*",
                    options: {
                        // comments: true,
                  //      baseDir: 'src/',
                        module: "amd",
                        target: "es5",
                        sourceMap: true,
                        declaration: true, //inlineSourceMap :true,
                        //emitDecoratorMetadata:true,
                        //experimentalDecorators:true,

                    }               

            }
```

and everything compiles fine:

"TypeScript compilation complete: 8.97s for 256 TypeScript files."

but then after changing a file (adding a linebreak) without changing the code the compile breaks with the watch:

```
### changed  >>src/FxsPortal/FxsBaseItemViewModel.ts
Compiling...
### Fast Compile >>src/FxsPortal/FxsBaseItemViewModel.ts
Using tsc v1.6.2
C:/dev/AscendXYZ Portal/src/FxsPortal/FxsBaseItemViewModel.ts(2,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'knockout'.
```

I know there are no errors since I can compile it all manually. I dont seem to understand why it do not work when the watch of ts-grunt triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference I just wanted to share how I solved this using an external watch.

```
 watch: {
            devBuildWatch: {
                files: ['src/**/*'],
                tasks: ['ts:devBuild'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false,
                },
            }
        },
```

and a onchange action

```
 var changedFiles = {};

    var onChange = grunt.util._.debounce(function () {
        grunt.config('ts.devBuild.src', Object.keys(changedFiles).concat([ "typings/vendors.d.ts","typings/tsd.d.ts", "!libs/**/*.ts"]));
        changedFiles = Object.create(null);
    }, 50);

    grunt.event.on('watch', function (action, filepath) {
        changedFiles[filepath] = action;
        onChange();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks - How is the "onchange" code linked to the watch task?

Comment: if you have a watch running, then grunt.event.on("watch" is firing on changes

Answer (score 0):

> I dont seem to understand why it do not work when the watch of ts-grunt triggers.

Those errors can be safely ignored. The reason why they show up is because grunt is just driving `tsc` from the command line and only passing it individual files.

## More

If you *really care* you can use `reference` tags to bring in the global `.d.ts` files (files that are not coming in via `import/require`). But I highly recommend against it. You should have an IDE open that will give you the *real* errors anways (*...cough atom-ts ...*)

Comment: Thanks! I will look into atom-ts. currently I am using the VS typescript project side by side to give highlight.  I understood the documentation such that reference was a outputfile? Is this wrong, so I can put my tsd.d.ts into reference? (can it take an array also)?

Comment: sorry, you ment reference in the ts files. not the option in ts-grunt

Comment: take a look at my answer for external watch.  If we had an option on ts-grunt such the internal watch did similar of concatting a list of type definitions.

Comment: Hi @basarat, I also encountered this issue. Is there a new solution for that? Ignoring the console is not a great one, kinda misses the purpose of watch IMO.

Comment: @basarat - the real issue here is that, true, I can ignore the errors and the file will compiled but since it's an error, when I'm undoing the latest code change I get: `No file changes were detected. Skipping Compile`- so I'm staying with the compiled code that produced the error.